# Pass more than 1 resultset to next mongoose.js promise chain

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongoose, promise

I am using mongoose.js promise. I am trying to have 2 finds in my chain and pass the both these result sets to the next link in the chain.
What I want to happen is that results from groups.find() and Users.find() are passed as an argument(s) into processResultsets. In this example groupList returns fine. But when I get to processResultsets I only have the Users from the previous link.

```
var promise =  groups
        .find()
        .sort('groupname')
        .exec();

promise
    .then(getWidgetsForGroups)
    .then(processResultsets)
    .catch(errFN);


function getWidgetsForGroups(groupList)
{

        return Users
            .find()
            .sort('name')
            .lean()
}

function processResultsets(rs1,rs2)
{
    ...
}

function errFN(err)
{
  ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

*If I've understood your question the right way:* It's not possible to get multiple results. Just use something like this code:

```
...
    .then(function(){
            return your_result_1
        }).then(function(){
            return your_result_2
        })...
```

Comment: Yeah that is what I was doing. I just curious if there was another way. thank-you

Comment: Ok. I don't know another way. I think the solution above would be the simplest way anyway. Sure no problem :) @GerryBrady